# How to format a mysql duplicate entry error?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, error-handling, mysql2

I'm using express.js with mysql2.

When a duplicate entry error happens on insertion I get the error in the global error handler and that works as expected.

When I log it to the console, the error looks like this:

```
   Error: Duplicate entry 'todd' for key 'users.username_UNIQUE'
    at PromisePool.execute (C:\Users\YT\Desktop\PORTFOLIO\MERN\social-talk\server\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:358:22)
    at C:\Users\YT\Desktop\PORTFOLIO\MERN\social-talk\server\models\User.js:45:48 {
  code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY',
  errno: 1062,
  sqlState: '23000',
  sqlMessage: "Duplicate entry 'todd' for key 'users.username_UNIQUE'"
}
```

**My issue is that I'm not sure how to format this error, because it doesn't give the actual field or key that is duplicate *(username)*, but just this sqlMessage field, which is not very good looking to display to the users in this format.**

PS: I'm aware of sequelize, but I'm really interested in how I can do this without an ORM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually came up with a decent solution.

Because the sqlMessage will always be in the same format, I first split the sqlMessage into an array, and then extracted the value entered, and then I also extracted the field, but since the field is in a format "database.field_UNIQUE", I had to extract the field that is in between the "." and "_" characters.

The code looks like this:

```
if (err.errno === 1062) {
    const errWords = err.sqlMessage.split(" ");
    const entry = errWords[2];
    const fieldDB = errWords[5];
    const formattedField = fieldDB.substring(fieldDB.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, fieldDB.lastIndexOf("_"));
    console.log( `Duplicate entry - ${formattedField}: ${entry}`)
    return res.status(400).json({ error: `Duplicate entry - ${formattedField}: ${entry}` });
}
```

The result will be:

> Duplicate entry - username: 'todd'

Comment: Thanks man for idea. instead of using `err.errno`. I am using `err.code`.